# display signal from stereo mics

Tags: audio, audio-processing

Are these 2 Audio Signals of Stereo?
[1st Signal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a0cqj.png)[2nd Signal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NWAue.png)

Answer (score 1):

hard to tell ... would be easier to identify whether those are stereo if both curves were plotted together with different color curves on same plot and zoomed in so you can see if the curves have similar shapes though slightly different ... if you create one loop to iterate across each point of the curve and inside this loop print out the sum of curve1 - curve2 on a per point basis then if the values of each of these sum values are close to zero then both curves are very similar and likely are stereo curves of same source sound

```
//  array1 holds all points of your signal 1
//  array2 holds all points of your signal 2

size_array = length(array1)  

for curr_index = 0; curr_index < size_array; curr_index++ {

    curr_sum = array1[curr_index] - array2[curr_index]   // inverts array2
    print $curr_sum
}
```

if both signals were identical above list of curr_sum would show value zero ( which means your signal is mono just copied into two channels )  ... if signals are stereo then curr_sum will be somewhat close to zero depending on degree of stereo separation between both microphones

Comment: Invert the phase  on 2nd signal; if mono, this produces pure silence.